# googleMap shows the world when activity first starts

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app I am utilizing google maps v2 api,

I have the below code, which when the activity first starts, shows the whole world with the blue pin showing my location. However, it does not zoom in to my direct location. However, whenever I call this method again after a while (using a show my location button), i do get zoomed it to the level I want.

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if(location != null)
    {

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        currentLat = location.getLatitude();

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        currentLon = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        if(googleMap != null)
        {               
                 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));   
                 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));

            LatLngBounds bounds = this.googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

            if (!bounds.contains(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())))
            {
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the camera position of the map view and the zoom level. Following code should work fine, provided that you have the correct lat and long to which the camera should move when the activity loads:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(17.385044,78.486671)).zoom(12).build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

You can learn a lot from this tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/